# Keep getting ORA-0096 missing expression for oracle db in c# application

Tags: c#, oracle

Question In my select variable I cant get it to work correctly each time I run it get

> ORA-0096 missing expression

I'm thinking it has something to do with the quotes. What I want to do do is search all of my records where the date is between my start_dp(datetimepicker) and my end_dp(datetimepicker) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 string cr; 
 cr = "SELECT * FROM con_dates WHERE DATE BETWEEN " + start_dp.Value.Date + " and " + end_dp.Value.Date + "";
```

I tried this expression with params but still the same exact error for oracle 
Date is a datetime data type and the value.date of both pickers should just be the date so I am not sure what is going on here...

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM con_dates WHERE ""date"" between :start and :end", dvconn);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("start", start_dp.Value.Date));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("end", end_dp.Value.date));
```

Comment: What is the value of cr after the concatenation? Are you sure that  start_dp.Value.Date return the date string in the right format. Try to use parameters and not concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would use the parameters on your example:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM con_dates WHERE \"date\" between :start and :end", dvconn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("start", OracleDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("end", OracleDbType.Date));

cmd.Parameters[0].Value = start_dp.Value;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = end_dp.Value;

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{

}

reader.Close();
```

Some notes:

- It looks like you were escaping your quotes VBA style...  to escape them in C# use the `\` backslash
- I am assuming `start_dp` and `end_dp` are date time edits or something where the `Value` property is an actual `DateTime`.  If not, then these need to be converted to actual date times.  ODP handles the dirty work, but the datatypes are important when you pass them to the parameters.
- If you can avoid it, I would seriously not name columns after datatypes, keywords, reserved words, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I think since `DATE` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) in Oracle, it does not sees your `DATE` as a column name but sees it as a function as [`DATE(expr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date). That's why it expects an expression after it.

You can escape it with using `"` as `"DATE"` but as a better way, change it to *non*-reserved word.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I tried this and still the same oracle error.  cr = "SELECT * FROM con_dates WHERE ""DATE"" BETWEEN " + start_dp.Value.Date + " and " + end_dp.Value.Date + ""; @Soner Gönül

Comment: @JamesBrown Do **not** use this way. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Updated my question where I used params instead but still the same oracle error. @Soner Gönül

Answer (score 0):

Try to add alias to your table name like con_dates c and then use c.DATE.